# The return type 'NewsModel' isn't a 'Widget' as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to build a News App that fetches data from the newsapi.org service and just when I am about to call the data inside the main method I am getting this error saying that my class 'NewsModel' isn't of the type 'Widget' as required by the closure's context. I have no idea what that means but here is my code for the app split into 2 files.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'models/news_model.dart';
import 'news_service.dart';
import 'package:assgn_digia_tech/models/news_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _loading = true;
  var newsList;
  List<NewsModel> articles = [];
  void getNews() async {
    newsService apiNews = newsService();
    await apiNews.getNews();
    articles = apiNews.apiNews;
    setState(() {
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getNews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            'News API',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[50],
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black, size: 26),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: _loading
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: articles.length,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return NewsModel(
                                title: articles[index].title,
                                description: articles[index].description,
                                author: articles[index].author,
                                content: articles[index].content,
                                urlToImage: articles[index].urlToImage,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:assgn_digia_tech/models/news_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class newsService {
  List<NewsModel> apiNews = [];

  Future<void> getNews() async {
    String apiUrl =
        'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=4e3474bb91ec49eda31b75e2daf6da3c';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonData['articles'].forEach((element) {
        if (element['urlToImage'] != null && element['description'] != null) {
          NewsModel article = NewsModel(
            title: element['title'],
            author: element['author'],
            description: element['description'],
            urlToImage: element['urlToImage'],
            content: element["content"],
          );
          apiNews.add(article);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return NewsModel(
```

You are supposed to return a `Widget` from the builder, because the purpose is to build a UI. Do you have a custom "NewsWidget" here, or do you want to build it from scratch? Maybe start by returning `Text(articles[index].title)` and then building it up from there to include all the other parts of your NewsModel.

Comment: Is the rest of the code right? I am assuming there are no logical errors?

Comment: I didn't look at the rest. This will fix the problem you had. If a new one pops up, try to solve it, if you cannot, get help here.